# exporting filtered audio using AudioKit 5

Tags: swift, audiokit

I've been unable to find any examples that walk one through how to export audio that you have piped through AudioKit's 5 filters.

I want to add some effect to the audio (like reverb..etc) then export filtered audio

here my try:

```
    // load empty file to write
    let docs = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let dstURL:URL =  docs.appendingPathComponent("rendred.caf")
    var audioFile:AVAudioFile!
    do {
        audioFile = try AVAudioFile(forReading: dstURL)
    } catch {
        Log("Could not load file")
    }
    
    // duration of audio after add some effects 
    let duration = self.conductor.player.duration
    let rendredTime = Double(duration)
    
    // using AudioEngine() to export mixed audio but it's not work <----
    do {
        try? self.conductor.engine.renderToFile(audioFile, duration: rendredTime, prerender: {
            self.conductor.player.play()
        })
    }
```

I'm not sure how `renderToFile()` function work

Comment: What is your question? What is an issue as far as the code you have posted above is concerned?

Comment: What is the flow of the export process that you are wanting to achieve? What type of audio are you trying to export? Is the audio coming from triggered samples, a local audio file, or live input that’s received from the built-in mic? 

Are you wanting to export the audio to share with others (via email, SoundCloud, text messages, etc), or do you just want to play back a rendered clip with the effect applied to it?

Comment: @MarkJeschke I'm trying to record normal audio with music in the background like Karaoke, but I'm not sure how to merge two audio and export it using "renderToFile()" function

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer  without your answers to what Mark Jeschke asked you but in general:

You can load the audio file, create a new reverb (like CostelloReverb for example).
Put the loaded audio as a node to the reverb.
Put the reverb as the output (again - it depends what exactly you want to do) to the AudioEngine output.

If you want to blend with playback you can use DryWetMixer.

Some general example:

```
import Foundation
import AudioKit
import SoundpipeAudioKit

class AudioProcessing {

let audioFile:(choose the way you want to load/play)
let playback :(same)
let reverb:CostelloReverb
let dryWetMix:DryWetMixer
let engine = AudioEngine()

    init() {
   
        (init the audioFile and playback here)

        reverb = CostelloReverb(audioFile)
        dryWetMix = DryWetMixer(playback, reverb)
        engine.output = dryWetMix
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your export probably does not work because your instance of `AVAudioFile` is created for reading and not for writing.

Instead of

```swift
AVAudioFile(forReading: dstURL)
```

you have to use

```swift
AVAudioFile(forWriting: fileURL, settings: [:])
```

### General recommendation

For any debugging purposes it is better to not silence the thrown error (by using `try?`). Instead it is always better to use `do catch`. At least during debugging.